# Angular 2 polling with RxJS

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs5

I'm trying to poll a RESTful endpoint to refresh my live chat messages. I know the best approach for a live chat would be Websockets, I'm just trying to understand how RxJS works with Angular 2.

I want to check for new messages every second. I have the following code:

```
return Rx.Observable
   .interval(1000)
   .flatMapLatest(() => this.http.get(`${AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT}/messages`))
   .map(response => response.json())
   .map((messages: Object[]) => {
      return messages.map(message => this.parseData(message));
   });
```

However my Typescript transpiler is returning this error:

> Property 'flatMapLatest' does not exist on type 'Observable<number>'

I'm using RxJS 5.0.0-beta.0

If I use **merge** instead of **flatMapLatest** it doesn't call the API at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `switchMap()`, there's no `flatMapLatest()` in RxJS 5.

See [Migrating from RxJS 4 to 5](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/blob/2b707faa5acf9245eb71e8529ba04b2a0d98ecd6/MIGRATION.md#operators-renamed-or-removed)... Although docs aren't very clear about `switchMap()`...

> Returns a new Observable by applying a function that you supply to each item emitted by the source Observable that returns an Observable, and then emitting the items emitted by the most recently emitted of these Observables.

Comment: How do I get the JSON out of switchMap? Typescript is returning this error: Property 'json' does not exist on type '{}'

Comment: Try to move `map()` out, and do it after `switchMap()`. I didn't use it myself, and docs aren't any help (;

Comment: In case anybody is wondering how to get the json out of switchMap, you need to type cast it like this: `.map((res: Response) => res.json())`. Make sure you imported **Response** from **'angular2/http'**

Answer (score 2):

To explain @Sasxa 's answer a bit more.

SwitchMap in illustration. (from http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html)

[image]