# How to make asynchronous REST API calls in ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am building an app for a school. Students can scan id cards and enter. On teacher's side application, I am showing number of students present in particular class. Now, I am using refresher to load page to show the number of students.

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
    <ion-refresher-content></ion-refresher-content>
  </ion-refresher>
</ion-content>



export class NumberOfStudents{
  doRefresh(refresher) {
    console.log('Begin async operation', refresher);
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Async operation has ended');
      refresher.complete();
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

Help me in achieving executing above code automatically in background without pulling to refresh. Give me an idea on how to call the api every 2 minutes or like that without affecting the view.

Comment: Do you mean polling? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35010182/angular-2-polling-with-rxjs

Comment: So, you do not want to use refresher?

Comment: hi yes..i dont want to use refresher

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care if the "refresh" API call take longer than your interval(2 minute), then you can use setInterval():

```
setInterval(doRefresh, 1000*60*2);
```